# exit an infinite loop?

Tags: python, loops

I'm getting into an infinite loop when I enter a non-integer. How do I fix it? Here's my code:

```
def inputInt(integer):
    while True:
        try:
            result = int(integer)
        except ValueError:
            print ('Invalid input - Try again')
            continue
        break
    return result
value = input (' Enter a value:')
number = inputInt(value)
print ('The value is',number)
```

Comment: ask the user to input an integer inside your function

Comment: How can the user try again as you only take the input outside of the loop?

Comment: continue starts the while Loop again with the same value

Comment: What needs to be fixed? I see nothing wrong with your code. What is it that you are trying to achieve?

Comment: You don't change `integer` within the loop.  Why do you have a loop?

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to achieve something like this?

```
def inputInt(acceptAny):
    while True:
        try :
            value = input (' Enter a value:')
            value = int(value)
        except ValueError:
            if acceptAny:
                break
            else:
                print ('Invalid input - Try again')
            continue
        break
    return value

if __name__ == "__main__":
    number = inputInt(False)
    print ('The value is',number)
```